# A piece of Colourful Language

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Well, I came home today and found my password being rejected. Cursing, I found a note on the underside of the compute. should never had told any of my friends my password. Curse them!

> Sorry BG :P
>
> We felt your password wasn't very secure so we helped you out and changed it. We didn't write it on the note here in case someone else opened your computer but we hid the new password in the puzzle below:
>
> [image]
> [image]
>
> The new password is a piece of Colourful Language.

### **Can you find my new password for me?**

<sub>[Google docs of pictures for those who cannot access imgur](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EltGfdRyFDoID2ukSdw2aNJIatBmVM74_MmKD1yM0BI/edit?usp=sharing).</sub>

---

<sub>Note: The final answer is NOT a swear word, don't worry about that :)</sub>

<sub>Note 2: I have added lines to the second image to match the colours so if anyone with colourblindness is struggling to differentiate the colours they should still be able to solve it now (click the images for a better picture -
the key is the squares at the top)</sub>

Comment: Is there a way to turn the picture into text? Specifically so that those who cannot access imgur can solve it? Also, that would help those who are colorblind.

Comment: @JakobLovern added a key for colourblind. I could add the images to a google docs sheet so you could access that?

Comment: @JakobLovern editted, see the link. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your password appears to be:

> rainbow

Starting with the image on the right:

> It is solved as a sudoku:
>  [image]

Then the image on the left:

> Using the solved sudoku, each row is rearranged to match the color order given above the sudoku. The left grid is rearranged in the same way to reveal this image:
>  [image]
>  The image shows a thunderstorm, a bow, and the words "7 letters".
>  The image is a rebus, with a 7 letter solution of rainbow (rain+bow).

Comment: You beat me. I'm at the arranging point (curse Microsoft paint for slowing me down). He shouldn't have drawn the thick lines in the 9x9 grid. They make it so obvious.

Comment: Possibly coincidence, but the colours used also correspond to the answer

Comment: @Tas the point was the whole question was to do with  colour :)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I wanted the sudoku bit to be obvious because I knew the rest would be a bit harder

Comment: @Apep Yep that’s the answer! A piece of colourful language indeed :)